# Animated Movements during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, web

There are a lot of websites which come up with creative summary pages these days. One such example is [Ideaware](http://ideaware.co/about/) and another [Art of Light](http://artofflightmovie.com/). I would like to know how exactly is this done? Is it done using any plugin or framework of HTML5? Or is it done by handling the scroll event for every position using javascript and manually writing code for each scroll position?

Comment: Did you find something from your own or tryied something so far ?

Comment: The way I can do it is by manually coding an event for every scroll position. But that seems to be very tedious and extremely time consuming. I tried looking into the source code and js files of the links and they do not seem to do it that way because the scroll event has been barely used.

Comment: **You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.** from [Questions you should not ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I do not think my question violates that rule. There was some webpage designed on the internet and I wanted to build something similar. All I wanted to know was the plugin used for such websites because I could not find it out. It was an answerable question as seen below. and an actual problem that I faced. It was neither chatty nor open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this plugin called Skollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I somehow knew that it wouldn't be done by handling every single scroll event. Are there more plugins like these?

Comment: Yes, there a lot of different plugins that can allow you to implement such effects.